# How is this function (for updating a Stochastic Gradient Descent model) called without a parameter?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I'm in the middle of a Deep Learning Course offered by DataCamp and the example below was given for optimizing a SGD model:

[image]

As you can see, the function "get_new_model" requires one parameter: "input_shape".  However, in line 9 there is no parameter given.  Why doesn't this throw an error?

Comment: The argument `input_shape` has been given some default value in the form of the `input_shape` variable.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about how default arguments work.